# Select is not working onClick IconComponent(dropdown-arrow) in react material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Below is my code snippet. I am facing an issue, when I click on IconComponent(*dropdown-arrow*), Select component is not opening.

```
<Select
  IconComponent={() => (
    <ExpandMore className="dropdown-arrow" />
  )}
  onChange={this.handleSelectUpdate.bind(this)}
  value={this.state.somestate}
  inputProps={{
    name: "someprops1",
    id: "someprops1"
  }}
  disabled={this.props.someprops1.length === 1}
  className="dropdown"
>
  >
  {_.map(this.props.someprops2, (item, id) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem value={item.somekey} key={id}>
        {item.somekey}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [`SelectInput.js`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js)(which `Select` leverages) the icon is rendered as follows:

```
<IconComponent className={classes.icon} />
```

With the manner that you were customizing the icon, you were ignoring the className property that `SelectInput` passes which prevented it from behaving correctly.

Below are a couple examples of customizing the icon. The first case uses the icon directly (`IconComponent={ExpandMoreIcon}`) without wrapping it in another function. The second case shows something closer to what you are trying to do (supporting specifying your own class on it). Though `className` is the only property that `SelectInput` tries to specify currently, I think you would be best off to pass through all the props:

```
const iconStyles = {
  selectIcon: {
    color: "green"
  }
};
const CustomExpandMore = withStyles(iconStyles)(
  ({ className, classes, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <ExpandMoreIcon
        {...rest}
        className={classNames(className, classes.selectIcon)}
      />
    );
  }
);
```

Here's the full example:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import clsx from "clsx";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
});
const iconStyles = {
  selectIcon: {
    color: "green"
  }
};
const CustomExpandMore = withStyles(iconStyles)(
  ({ className, classes, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <ExpandMoreIcon
        {...rest}
        className={clsx(className, classes.selectIcon)}
      />
    );
  }
);

class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: "",
    name: "hai"
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            IconComponent={ExpandMoreIcon}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            IconComponent={CustomExpandMore}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

SimpleSelect.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleSelect);
```

[image: Edit Select custom icon]

Here is the styling that Material-UI adds to the icon (found in [`NativeSelect.js`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/NativeSelect/NativeSelect.js#L70) which exports its styles so that [`Select.js`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.js#L10) can reuse them):

```
  icon: {
    // We use a position absolute over a flexbox in order to forward the pointer events
    // to the input and to support wrapping tags..
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 'calc(50% - 12px)', // Center vertically
    pointerEvents: 'none', // Don't block pointer events on the select under the icon.
    color: theme.palette.action.active,
    '&$disabled': {
      color: theme.palette.action.disabled,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the icon component if the popup is open. */
  iconOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
  },
  /* Styles applied to the icon component if `variant="filled"`. */
  iconFilled: {
    right: 7,
  },
  /* Styles applied to the icon component if `variant="outlined"`. */
  iconOutlined: {
    right: 7,
  },
```

The absolute positioning keeps the icon within the clickable area of the `Select`. Without the absolute positioning, the icon will cause the different elements making up the Select to shift. Clicking in the place where the icon **should** be continues to work, but the way elements get shifted causes the overall layout of the Select to no longer make sense.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this saved a lot of time.

Comment: What is the typescript version? I get Property 'classes' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<ConsistentWith<ConsistentWith<{}, { classes: Record<"selectIcon", string>; }>, { classes: Record<"selectIcon", string>; }> | ConsistentWith<...>>'.

Comment: `className={classNames(className, classes.selectIcon)}`

This requires that you install the classnames package. The CodeSandbox fails because that dependency is missing. With MUI it is probably better to use clsx, as it is included already. https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#whats-the-clsx-dependency-for

Comment: @ØysteinGrandeJaren v3 of Material-UI (the current version when I wrote this answer) included the `classnames` package. They replaced it with `clsx` in v4. I've updated my example and changed the sandbox to use a specific version of Material-UI rather than "latest", so it doesn't break in this fashion again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using material UI Icons then simply add below 3 lines of css in your Icon component:

```
position: absolute !important;
right: 0 !important;
pointer-events: none !important;
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to set in className pointer events as none and position - absolute for the icon, and position - relative for select.

here is an example:

```
icon: {
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  position: 'absolute',
  right: '10px'
},
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on mui v 4.12.3