# Change the place of arrow in selection text fields in mui for react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-UI for ReactJS. The component I have question about is select text fields.

Now the dropdown arrow is on the right side of the text field and I want to move it to the left side.
Can anyone help me with this?!

```
<TextField
        id="outlined"
        select
        label="Select"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.data}
        onChange={handleChange}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu,
          }
        }}
        helperText="Please select your data"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
      >
        {data.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
</TextField>
```

Comment: In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929613/select-is-not-working-onclick-iconcomponentdropdown-arrow-in-react-material-ui/54930510#54930510) you can find some details about the icon (i.e. arrow) styling that may be helpful to get you started.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks! I'll check it out