# How do I use an SVG as an IconComponent in a Material UI Select?

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui

I have

```
import CaretDownIcon from 'src/../public/images/svg/caret-down.svg';


      <Select
        className={selectClassName}
        data-testid={testId}
        // IconComponent={<SvgIcon>{CaretDownIcon}</SvgIcon>}
        // IconComponent={CaretDownIcon}
        inputProps={{
          name,
          id: labelId,
        }}
        {...rest}
      >
```

I tried both of those commented lines, but no dice. What's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a component for your custom svg icon. Copy the path from the svg file to make a component as shown below:

```
function CustomSvgIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

then you can use that with `IconComponent={CustomSvgIcon}`.

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
});
function CustomSvgIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: "",
    name: "hai"
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            IconComponent={CustomSvgIcon}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

SimpleSelect.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleSelect);
```

[image: Edit Select custom icon]

It is also possible to create a React component from an imported SVG file, but this is dependent on your build configuration. If you are using `create-react-app` then this will work (see [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/) for details).

Below is an example using the import approach. This uses `import { ReactComponent as TestSvgAsComponent } from "./test.svg";` to get a React component from the SVG file. The other step necessary is to add in the styles that would be applied by SvgIcon (`classes.icon` from `useIconStyles` in the example).

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { ReactComponent as TestSvgAsComponent } from "./test.svg";
import clsx from "clsx";
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
});
const useIconStyles = makeStyles({
  // This is a copy of the styles from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.js#L10
  icon: {
    fill: "currentColor",
    width: "1em",
    height: "1em",
    display: "inline-block",
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    transition: "fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms",
    flexShrink: 0,
    userSelect: "none"
  }
});

function CustomSvgIcon({ className, ...other }) {
  const classes = useIconStyles();
  return (
    <TestSvgAsComponent className={clsx(classes.icon, className)} {...other} />
  );
}
class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: "",
    name: "hai"
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            IconComponent={CustomSvgIcon}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

SimpleSelect.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleSelect);
```

[image: Edit Select custom icon]

Related documentation:

- https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svgicon

Related answer:

- [Select is not working onClick IconComponent(dropdown-arrow) in react material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929613/select-is-not-working-onclick-iconcomponentdropdown-arrow-in-react-material-ui/54930510#54930510)

Comment: But I don't have the `<path>`, etc. I simply have the SVG file, so how would I use that?

Comment: The `<path>` element will be inside the SVG file. Open the file in a text editor and copy that part.

Comment: Any way to import it?

Comment: See the additions to my answer (second example).